# Program not running after inputting 1,000,000 numbers?

Tags: c

I made myself a little prime checking program and it works perfectly, however, after inputting a million numbers it crashes.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* Prototypes */
void primeChecker(int num1, int num2);

int main() {
    int startNumber = 1000;
    int endNumber = 1000000;

    primeChecker(startNumber, endNumber);

    /* Stops the program */
    return (0);
}

void primeChecker(int num1, int num2) {
    int isPrime, i, count = 0;

    int number1 = num1;
    int number2 = num2;

    while (number1 <= number2) {
        /* Assume isPrime is true */
        isPrime = 1;

        for (i = 2; i < number1 && isPrime; i++) {
            if (number1 % i == 0) {
                isPrime = 0;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime == 1) {
            count++;
            //printf("%d ", num1);
        }
        number1++;
    }
    printf("There are %d prime numbers between %d and %d", count, num1, num2);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: It could be out of memory. There's a reason it's hard to find primes.

Comment: `count++;` possible overflow target

Comment: @self Basically if there is a prime number then count increments by 1. At the end of that method it prints how many prime numbers (count) was found.

Comment: You should look into the multitude of ways to look into if a number is prime. I'll take it that somewhere along, your ints are overflowing.

Comment: What do you mean "after inputting a million numbers"?  Your program doesn't accept input.  It just calculates.

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: @paddy Ah, wasn't getting technical. You already know what I mean.

Comment: Actually, I don't.  Is this the _actual_ program that has the problem?

Comment: @fluter Well, it doesn't necessarily crash. It just stalls. So I'm not sure if it's still calculating or if it's not doing anything.

Comment: Then it does not crash, it is just not finishing...

Comment: A crash is completely different from a hang.  It's a **O(n^2)** implementation so it's going to be slow.  You can figure out what it's doing by printing out the value of `number1` in the main loop.  Or you can use a debugger.  If it's actually looping indefinitely, most likely it's because the size of your `int` cannot hold a value of 1000000.  Otherwise, your compiled code is unoptimised or the system is slow, and you just need to wait.

Comment: I cannot reproduce crash. Copied code, compiles and runs fine with GCC on Linux and after about 3 minutes it outputs `There are 78330 prime numbers between 1000 and 1000000`, which seems correct.

Comment: first does not divide by all the number to number1 divide by all the number to (number/2)

Comment: Break out the loop here early: `if (number1 % i == 0) { isPrime = 0; break; }` This can save a lot of modular operations.

Comment: to optimize the process when you get all the prime number to number1 store them if number1 is also a prime number store it. on the next look, use all the prime number which are all <= (number1 / 2) to test if the next number is prime or not

Comment: Try the [sieve of what's his name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). You can also search `[c] prime` here on SO for plenty of different methods to find primes.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code. Your algorithm is just *very* ineffective, so your program will take some minutes to run (took 2 minutes on my computer, yours may be slower).

You can see this if you change the line

```
//printf("%d ", num1);
```

which, I presume, you have been using to debug, with

```
printf("%d\n", number1);
```

since `number1` is actually the number that gets changed in the loop (`num1` is constant throughout the function call). The program will then count, slowly, all the primes from 1,000 to 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe your code causes a crash, it just takes a couple of minutes to run because of the inefficiency in your algorithm.

To improve your code's runtime, try writing a more efficient prime checking algorithm. For example, for the primeChecker function, only mod number1 with all the prime numbers smaller than sqrt(number1), which is sufficient to determine its primeness. This will then require you to check all the numbers starting from 2, 3, 5, .. etc for their primeness and produce an array of the prime numbers up until number2, but will overall save you more on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct prime_int* p_t;

struct prime_int
{
  int num;
  p_t next;
};
//this to create a list of prime integer
p_t new_pt(int n, p_t p)
{
    p_t t = malloc(sizeof(struct prime_int));
    t->num = n;
    t->next = p;
    return t;
}
//this to test the number by dividing it by all the prime number
//between 2 and its middle if it cannot be divide it is prime
// and we add it to the list of integer
void prime(int n, p_t p){
    p_t new_pt(int v, p_t k);
    int b = n/2;
    p_t t = p, tmp = NULL;
    while(t){
            if(t->num > b) break;
            else
            {
                tmp = t;
                if(n%(t->num))t = t->next;
                else return;
            }
          }
    if(!tmp)return;
    while(tmp->next)tmp=tmp->next;
    tmp->next = new_pt(n, NULL);
}
//just to print all the prime number and free the previously 
//allocated data and print the total number of prime integer
int affiche(p_t p)
{
    int i = 0;
    p_t tmp = NULL;
    while(p)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->num);
        i++;
        tmp = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    return i;
}

int main(){
   int affiche(p_t p);
   int i = 3;
   void prime(int n, p_t p);
   p_t new_pt(int n, p_t p);
   p_t deb = new_pt(2,new_pt(3, NULL));
   while(1)
   {
        prime(i,deb);
        if(i>1000000)break;
        i+=2;
   }
   i = affiche(deb);
   printf("\n total number of prime integer %d", i);
   return 1;
}
```

**After execution**

total number of prime integer 78498

Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 50.575 s

Answer (score -2):

This is definitely not the most efficient method and it took quite some time to execute, but here's my solution. Prime calculates if the number is prime using a simple increment and mod check. If the number is prime, return 1 or not prime return 0 (which will be added to count). The reason I'm using uint64_t here is that it was originally designed to handle much larger numbers, but feel free to change it to an int if necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int prime(uint64_t N){
    uint64_t i;
    for(i=2;i<=N/2;++i){
        if(N%i==0){ return 0; }
    } return 1;
}

int main(){
  int i, count=0;
  for ( i = 1000; i < 1000000; i++ )
    count+=prime(i);

  printf("Count is %d.\n", count);
}
```

Count is 78330.